# Retrieve Web Browser Stored Form Data?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, cross-browser

I have my web browsers set to save what I type into text boxes on forms.  I have a lot of search terms stored in the text box of my browser and would like to get at it via a program of some sort before I clear these values out.  There are far too many for me to go through one at a time.

The web browser must store this data somewhere, does anyone know where?  Is it possible to retrieve these values?   *Firefox*, more so than IE -- but either, if anyone knows a script that can extract these values? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firefox 3**

In Firefox on Windows it's stored in a SQLite file, in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<Username>\Application Data
    \Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<UID>.default\formhistory.sqlite
```

Once you have the SQLite file, you can put together a script to read the data from it pretty quickly - here's a good primer to [using SQLite with PHP 5](http://www.weberdev.com/ViewArticle/Introduction-to-using-PHP-5.0-and-SQLite) for example.

**Firefox pre-version 3**

Apparently SQLite has only been used for the saved form history since version 3. Version 2 still uses formhistory.dat, which is written using [Mork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_(file_format)).

From the wiki on Mork:

> Also, despite being plain text, Mork is generally regarded as unintelligible to humans and as a hard format to write parsers for.

There has been an item files [on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=241438) asking for a more sane and readable format to be introduced, the filer even [attempted to write a perl parser](http://www.jwz.org/hacks/mork.pl) for his .dat files, with limited success.

Comment: I dont have a formhistory.sqlite file.  ALL I have is a formhistory.dat file.  I searched the entire drive for that..  Got other .sqlite files but nothing that would indicate its form history.  I am on FF 2.0.0.15

Comment: My bad, it would appear that sqlite is built in from 3 onwards. What's in your formhistory.dat file? That should be the same thing.

Comment: Best of luck with it! On a couple of the FF pre-3 links above, various people have mentioned upgrading to 3 auto-converted their .dats to sqlite, so might be worth a try. But definitely back up your profile dir first, just incase!

Comment: Thats part of why I asked...  my installation is hosed and I have decided to install clean and fresh - everything.  I will probably go to FF3 but not via an upgrade.   I had wanted to capture what I had typed into one particular search box.  Ugh.  Seems harder than necessary with FF2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can find the form history in the form of a sqlite database under USER_DIR/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles//formhistory.sqlite

I didn't try to browse it with Sqlite but the filename seems to be explicit.

You can find several wrappers on the [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers) website to access it from the language of your choice.

Good Luck